# Slicing satellite knots

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Call a knot L a "braid-pattern satellite" of a knot K if it is a satellite of K and the pattern on which it is based is a closed braid in the solid torus.  Is there a knot K so that no braid-pattern satellite L is smoothly slice, i.e. bounds a smoothly embedded disk in the 4-ball?

Comment: Would nonzero signature obstruct that?

Comment: @JimConant: looks like not: see Theorem 2 of this paper: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/litherland.pdf

Comment: As a partial answer, by Theorem 1.2 of this paper by Jeff Meier, there are knots (e.g. the right-handed trefoil or its positive Whitehead double) for which no positive cable is smoothly slice https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04562